# jQuery Selector returns function instead of DOM

Tags: jquery, html, dom

This is an odd one..

The followings are taking place well after the page has been loaded.
I'm trying to add a class to a known (I know the element's id) DOM element.

```js
$('#day-08-07-2016')
```

However, this returns back a jQuery function, not the DOM element.
[image]

Since the selector is an Id and there is only one element on the page, i can't use the [0] or first() functions.

Ultimately, the followings doesn't work!

```js
$('#day-08-07-2016').addClass('active')
```

The element clearly exists on the page.
[image]
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem you have is that the element isn't found, probably because it doesn't exist

Comment: Are you using document.ready function?  If not how do you know when all the dom is available?

Comment: The element does exist. This event is running as a 'change' to the dropdownlist. So, the page has already been loaded.

Comment: FYI: jQuery _always_ returns a function - itself, to be more exact - because otherwise method chaining would not work in the first place.

Comment: Document.ready.

Comment: `id="foo"` and `id="#foo"` are different things.

Comment: `$('#foo')` searches for `id="foo"` - but you have `id="#foo"`. The element you're looking for doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title of your question isn't really related.  jQuery selectors always return a deferred function of sorts.  Commonly called a jQuery set wrapper.  In this case, it's wrapping an empty set.

I think your real confusion here is caused by the `#` that you put in the id.  Get the `#` out of the id and you'll be fine.  Alternatively, see other answers on escaping it.

Answer (score 2):

You're not finding the element because `$('#day-08-07-2016')` looks for an ID of `day-08-07-2016`.

Because your ID is already prefixed with a `#`, if you intend to keep it that way, you'd probably have to do:

```
$('[id="#day-08-07-2016"]').addClass('active');
```

**EDIT:** As [DaniP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887133/danip) suggests in the comments, you could also escape the `#` by doing:

```
$('#\\#day-08-07-2016')
```

Comment: Or `$('#\\#day-08-07-2016')`

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in the other answers - jQuery selector **always** returns a jQuery object (which you referred to as "function").

If you want to select some elements by id where the id starts with `#` - you should escape that char (using `\\#`).

Here is an example:

```js
$(function() {
  console.log($('#\\#abc').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="#abc">content</div>
```

Comment: I should've mentioned that i'm using jQuery 1.9.1. Your solution doesn't apply for me!

Comment: Updated the code to use jQuery 1.9.1 and everything works. Check again...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know about your real mistake go to console of any browser,

in that add id of the any element with prefix '#'

then select the element using below js,

```
$("#test")
```

the result will be like object :

**init {context: document, selector: "#test"}**

if you try like below:

```
$("##test")
```

you will face the following error:

**jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ##test(…)**

then remove # prefix from your ID then try

```
$("#test")
```

the result will be like below,

**[a#test]**

Always avoid to use prefix '#' for id of the element and avoid to use prefix '.' for class of the element...

Answer (score 0):

In css selectors the symbol `#` denotes an id whereas a `.` denotes a class.

`$('.my-item')` will return the jquery wrapped element which looks like `<a class='myitem' href='#'>`

`$('#my-item')` will return the jquery wrapped element which looks like `<a id='myitem' href='#'>`

In your case, it looks like your id values start with a #. In order to make your selector work, you have 2 options:

1) Escape the # character in your css selector. In this case your query will become `$('#\\#day-08-07-2016').addClass('active')`

2) Change your ids so that they do not start with the # character, and your query can remain the same.

Personally I would go with 2 here.